# Does it make sense to say that ones' interest in something is "instrumental" if

Tags: meaning, word-choice

if the interest was born out of some personal goal?

For instance:

> My interest in grammar is both academic, in that I enjoy studying
>   languages, and instrumental, in that I hope to become a grammar
>   teacher one day.

Comment: I'd choose *practical* or *pragmatic* over *instrumental*, there. You'd typically use *instrumental* **after** something has proven its value or indispensability; in this scenario, after you *become* a grammar teacher.

Comment: Please look 'instrumental' up in a dictionary - and consider why or why not it may be suitable. Then come back & expand your question.  One reason for closing a Q. is "Please include the research you've done, .... Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this does not make sense. Partly because you are mixing a present participle[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/verb-tenses-adding-ed-and-ing) and a future tense:

> My interest in grammar is both academic, in that **I enjoy studying** languages, and instrumental, in that **I hope to become** a grammar teacher one day.

Also partly because the word 'instrumental' in the sense of:

> Serving as a means of pursuing an aim[2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/instrumental)

...is an adjective, which means it should be an attribute of a noun.

So you could say this:

> My enjoyment of, and academic interest in grammar has been instrumental in my studies.

Comment: I selected your answer, but isn't instrumental in the correct place for an adjective? The noun is "my interest in grammar".

Comment: The place of instrumental may be correct, however, "my interest in grammar" is not a quite a noun, but a noun phrase.